# Error on using SharedMediaTask GetPath() for image sharing

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, media-library

I am trying to share a photo from media library via `SharedMediaTask` but I am getting error from `GetPath()`. The error says:

> Error 1 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media.MediaLibrary' does not contain a definition for 'GetPath' and the best extension method overload...

Here is my code for photo sharing via `SharedMediaTask`:

```
//Open Saved image from isolated storage
IsolatedStorageFile Store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
IsolatedStorageFileStream toShare = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(filePath1, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, Store);

//Save image to media library
MediaLibrary library = new MediaLibrary();
library.SavePicture("Memefy_Photo", toShare);

//Open ShareMediaTask
var task = new ShareMediaTask();
task.FilePath = library.GetPath(); //<----THIS is where the error appears :(
task.Show();
```

Also I have use this `using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media.PhoneExtensions;` to enable the `GetPath()` as it is needed based on my research.

Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetPath` is defined on the picture, not on the media library.

```
//Save image to media library
MediaLibrary library = new MediaLibrary();
var picture = library.SavePicture("Memefy_Photo", toShare);

//Open ShareMediaTask
var task = new ShareMediaTask();
task.FilePath = picture.GetPath();
task.Show();
```

Comment: The above answer is correct. but you have to add a namespace... using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media.PhoneExtensions; after adding this namespace you can use the picture.GetPath() method.